# How to copy a powershell script from a SCM repo to a windows machine through vmware_vm_shell ansible module

Tags: ansible, infrastructure-as-code, vmware

I wanted to execute a powershell script to add a local user to a windows machine without using  a winrm connection. Hence i tried to copy the file from the scm repo to the windows vm and run it .I used anisble community.vmware.vmware_vm_shell module to do this task.

```
---
- name: Stage source vm
  hosts: cloned_group
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files: 
    - common-vars.yml
#
  tasks:
    - name: copy file to vm
      community.vmware.vmware_guest_file_operation:
         hostname: "{{ vcenter_host }}"
         username: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
         password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
         datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
         vm_id: "{{ parent_vm }}"
         vm_username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
         vm_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
         copy:
          src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/ps-scripts/local_user_add.ps1"
          dest: "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\winrmconfig.ps1"
          overwrite: false
```

Running the above playbook gives me the below error

```
{
  "uuid": "420fef7e-ad78-9011-7e75-a62d32a2cf7f",
  "msg": "problem during file transfer, http message:{'url': 'https://pesxi-5.jersey.se:443/guestFile?id=5623&token=52b5fc4d-3fc0-10a3-81ad-bf5cc792802a5623', 'status': -1, 'msg': 'Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>'}",
  "invocation": {
    "module_args": {
     
      "copy": {
        "src": "/runner/project/ps-scripts/local_user_add.ps1",
        "dest": "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\winrmconfig.ps1",
        "overwrite": false
      },
      "validate_certs": false,
      "port": 443,
      "vm_id_type": "vm_name",
      "timeout": 100,
      "proxy_host": null,
      "proxy_port": null,
      "cluster": null,
      "folder": null,
      "directory": null,
      "fetch": null
    }
  },
  
}
```